# HP PS/2 style keyboard preventing suspend

Tags: keyboard

We have openSUSE Tumbleweed running on this machine. We had attached a wireless HP keyboard to the machine and suspend worked well from what I could tell. The issue is the keyboard was not taking keys correctly. It became very very frustrating for us to use.

Attached to the machine now is an older HP PS/2 style keyboard. It’s solid and never misses a keystroke.

```
:~> /usr/sbin/hwinfo --keyboard
25: PS/2 00.0: 10800 Keyboard                                   
  [Created at input.226]
  Unique ID: nLyy.+49ps10DtUF
  Hardware Class: keyboard
  Model: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Vendor: 0x0001 
  Device: 0x0001 "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
  Compatible to: int 0x0211 0x0001
  Device File: /dev/input/event0
  Device Files: /dev/input/event0, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
  Device Number: char 13:64
  Driver Info #0:
    XkbRules: xfree86
    XkbModel: pc104
  Config Status: cfg=no, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
:~>
```

This keyboard now is preventing suspend from working fully. Yes, suspend does shut off the monitor but it leaves the machine in a running state when invoked. I have investigated the bios settings and can not find anything pertaining to the PS/2 style keyboard in there.

What can we do to try to get suspend to work correctly with the PS/2 style keyboard attached now?